# It appears imageLabeler cannot handle a transformed datastore?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The Matlab app [imageLabeler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/imagelabeler-app.html?searchHighlight=imagelabeler&s_tid=srchtitle) is supposed to support the following format:

```
imageLabeler(imgStore)
```

I have an imgStore, defined as follows:

```
imds = imageDatastore(cellArrayOfImageFilenames);
imgStore = transform(imds, @(x)demosaic(x,'rggb'));
```

I have to do this, because my images are stored as bayer encoded images, and this is the only way I've figured out to get the imgStore to return these images as 3 channel RGB images.  However, when I try and initalize imageLabeler, I get this error:

```
>> imageLabeler(imgStore)
Error using imageLabelerInternal
Expected input name to be one of these types:

char

Instead its type was matlab.io.datastore.TransformedDatastore.

Error in vision.internal.imageLabeler.imageLabelerInternal

Error in imageLabeler (line 58)
vision.internal.imageLabeler.imageLabelerInternal(varargin{:});
```

TLDR:
How do I get imageLabeler to handle my bayer encoded images?

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this, is with the imageDatastore 'ReadFcn' parameter.  The documentation for [imageDatastore](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.html) *explicity* tells you to NOT do this, as it slows down Neural Network stuff.  Here's the Matlab doc text:

> Using ReadFcn to transform or pre-process 2-D images is not
> recommended. For file formats recognized by imformats, specifying
> ReadFcn slows down the performance of imageDatastore. For more
> efficient ways to transform and pre-process images, see Preprocess
> Images for Deep Learning (Deep Learning Toolbox).

So, all that said, here's the workaround:

```
imgStore = imageDatastore(cellArrayOfImageFilenames ...
            , 'ReadFcn', @(x)demosaic(imread(x),'rggb')));
```

Comment: It would be good to bolster your answer with the link to and text from the "explicit" documentation against this